Resources on the Creation of Economic Value
I'm searching for comprehensive treatises on how the various philosophical traditions see the creation of economic value.
The Wikipedia page linked in the comments isn't as exhaustive as I'd like, e.g. it doesn't account for Bataille's view on value.

Economics question. Please stop adding tags "philosophy-of-whatever" to ask questions about whatever on this SE.

@armand can you expand on why you don't think this is a question about philosophy?

you should investigate how was money created in our civilization and its relation to debt.

There are several theories of value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(economics)#Theories

Since value is a philosophical concept or is at least open to philosophical analysis, the kinds of value (including the economic) are open to analysis as well. On these grounds I have re-opened the question.
